# AWS S3 throws exception intermittently

Tags: amazon-s3

AWS S3 throws the following exception intermittently. It happens while

> Source : System, Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,
>
> Inner Exception : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size),
>
> Stack trace :    at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.CachingWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

Comment: @StuartLC, Thanks a lot for your reply. I need to understand how to fix this. It is happening while I do Load testing. I see this issue happens everyday. There are around ~7 such failures everyday in approx. 1,50,000 upload/download request to AWS S3. As per your comment, I understand that a retry may help me to resolve this. Apart from retry, is there anything else that can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Where you able to ever fix this issue? I am having a similar problem with uploading files in S3 using powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Based on thread [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/450), I think this is an internal bug in Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.CachingWrapperStream.Read not fixed yet.
To handle this error, I have to record all failed files and re-do at the tailing part. This happens now and then, so I put calculation and logic checks to later procedure and finish this download as soon as possible.